# Gluing together Riemann surfaces, don't see why $Z$ is union of two compact sets.

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces, several-complex-variables

Consider Lemma 1.7 from page 60-61 of Miranda's *Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces*. For a link to the book, see [here](http://tomlr.free.fr/Math%E9matiques/Fichiers%20Claude/Algebraic%20Curves%20and%20Riemann%20Surfaces-R.Miranda%20(AMS,%201995).pdf).

> **Lemma 1.7.** *With the above construction, $Z$ is a compact surface of genus $g$. The meromorphic function $x$ on $X$ extends to a holomorphic map $\pi: Z \to \mathbb{C}_\infty$, which has degree $2$. The branch points of $\pi$ are the roots of $h$ (and the point $\infty$ if $h$ as odd degree).*
>
> ***Proof.*** One checks readily that $Z$ is Hausdorff, and hence is a Riemann surface. $Z$ is compact, since it is the union of two compact sets$$\{(x, y) \in X : \|x\| \le 1\} \text{ and }\{(z, w) \in Y : \|z\| \le 1\}.$$

To me, I don't see why $Z$ is the union of the above two compact sets. Can anyone clarify? Thanks.

Comment: How to show precisely that $Z$ is Hausdorff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two given sets are indeed compact, since $h$ and $k$ are bounded in modulus on the indicated unit disks. Now the point is just that in the first coordinate, the gluing map is $z = \tfrac{1}{x}$, so the exterior of the first set (i.e. $\{ (x,y)\in \mathbb C^2 \, | \, ||x|| > 1 \}$ ) is mapped to $\{ (z,w) \in \mathbb C^2 \, | \, 0 < ||z|| < 1 \}$. Thus every point of $X$ with $||x|| > 1$ is mapped to a point of $Y$ with $||z|| < 1$, and these two compacta cover $Z$.

Comment: How to show that $Z$ is Hausdorff?

Comment: You can break the types of pairs of points in $Z$ into a few cases (based on which of the covering sets each point lives in). Now for each case choose separating neighborhoods, and check that they remain disjoint under the gluing operation.

Comment: Assume $h(0)\ne 0$. Observe that $X-U=\{(0,√(h(0)),(0,-√h(0))\}$ and $Y-V=\{ (0,1),(0,-1)\}$ . 

All the elements of ${X\coprod Y}/\phi$ looks like either $\{(x,y)\}$ if $(x,y)\in X-U$ or $\{(z,w)\}$ if $(z,w)\in Y-V$  or $\{(x,y),\phi(x,y)\}$ of $(x,y)\in U$.

Take two distinct element from the gluing space say $P=\{(x_1,y_1),\phi(x_1,y_1)\}$ and $Q=\{(x_2,y_2),\phi(x_2,y_2)\}$ ,$(x_1,y_1)\ne (x_2,y_2)$ .Take two disjoint open sets $B_1,B_2$ in $\mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{C}$ containing $(x_1,y_1)$ and. $(x_2,y_2)$ respectively.

Comment: Now  under the inclusion map of $X$ in the glued space $i_1$ image $i_1(B_1\cap U)$ and $i_2(B_2\cap U)$ are two disjoint open set containing $P,Q$ respectively.
Because $\{Z_1,\phi(Z_1)\}$ and $\{Z_2,\phi(Z_2)\}$ in any gluing space equal if and only if $Z_1=Z_2$ and $\phi(Z_1)=\phi(Z_2)$.

More or less same argument for elements in $X-U$ and $Y-V$